# How to expand URL with mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.2

I need to do the following URL rewriting:

```
/.*  -> /test/$1
```

How can I set it up with `mod_rewrite`?

This is my full config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName main.domain
  ServerAlias supplementary.domain
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^supplementary\.domain$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /supplementary$1 [NS]  <-- doesn't work
  <Location "/supplementary">
    .. custom config ..
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're missing the leading slash in the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following mod_rewrite config

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ! ^/test/
>   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$         /test/$1

**Update**:

> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$         /test/$1 [NS]

Comment: In this case `/test/` won't be forwarded, right? It's not a correct approach, since I still want `/test/` to be forwarded to `/test/test/`

Comment: Ok, then try to append `[NS]`to the RewriteURL and leave away the RewriteCond. I’ll edit the example above.

Comment: see the updated question. Currently it doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide some more information? Where exactly to you insert the rules? You could add a [rewrite log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) as well to debug whether the rules are applied at all.

Answer (score 0):

If neither of Adrian Lang's examples work you could try something like this. The rewrite conditions will prevent it from doing further rewrites if the file exists.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /test/$1
```